# How do I install mongodb on the beaglebone black

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

Has anyone had any success running mongodb on the beaglebone black? do I have to install a different flavor of linux to get this to work or can I use angstrom.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB (as at 2.4) does not officially support ARM processors. You can watch/upvote [SERVER-1811](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811) in the issue tracker, however I wouldn't expect this to get much traction until there are 64-bit server-class ARM processors commonly available.

In general a 32-bit low power ARM processor with limited memory (512Mb RAM on the BeagleBone Black) is not a great fit for a memory-mapped database server like MongoDB. Due to the use of memory-mapped files, 32-bit versions of MongoDB are also [limited to about 2GB of data and indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-the-limitations-of-32-bit-versions-of-mongodb).

There are some extremely old versions of MongoDB that have been hacked to work on ARM to some extent (eg: [MongoDB 2.1.1-pre](http://www.timandpaige.com/technology/installing-mongodb-on-the-raspberry-pi-part-1-introduction)), which is a *very* early development release of MongoDB 2.2. I wouldn't recommend this unless you're extremely desperate; likely you will spend far more time trying to get things working than writing productive code.

Better approaches would be to either:

- use a database which is designed for lightweight environments (eg. SQLite)
- use your BeagleBone to run a MongoDB *client* application rather than a *server*

Comment: While ARM is still (as at MongoDB 2.6) not an officially supported architecture, I've heard of some Pi users having success with the [ArchLinux ARM package for MongoDB](http://archlinuxarm.org/packages?search=mongodb).