# Is there a MongoDB 2.4+ installation available for Arm chips?

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, odroid

I'm interested in building a small server using the [Odroid U3](http://hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) which has 1.7GHz Quad-Core chip. I did install MongoDB 2.1.1 on a Raspberry but found the performance far too low for any serious usage other than tinkering. I was wondering there is a MongoDB package/instruction/tutorial somewhere to install newer versions of MongoDB. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to clone it from git hub and see if you can compile the code for ARM.

Comment: Ok, the problem is I don't know where to start. When I installed 2.1.1 I just followed an online tutorial. I'll try following the tutorial using 2.4.x instead. Thanks!

Comment: This link has the details about the build requirements - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md Check if  it helps you

Comment: ARM isn't an officially supported architecture for MongoDB yet, and 32-bit CPUs like the Odroid are definitely not recommended for anything other than tinkering (they'll have a total limit of ~2Gb of data & indexes for memory-mapped files, which is halved if you want to enable journaling). For a similar question, see: [How do I install mongodb on the beaglebone black](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338008/how-do-i-install-mongodb-on-the-beaglebone-black). The long overdue 64-bit ARM server-class CPUs are finally making an appearance in 2014, which will make ARM support more appealing.

Comment: I suggest you watch/upvote [SERVER-1811: ARM  support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811) in the MongoDB issue tracker, which also has some comments from folks experimenting on ARM platforms.

Comment: @Stennie - I do realise that, however in my case, it'd be a production server which would have a very limited scope and usage (the server would only have a maximum of 10 connections at any given time and the db would never reach 500MB - I have a script that would backup and empty every so often) so I guess the Droid would suffice until the 64-bit Arm arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really up to date version of MongoDB for Arm chips on [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MongoDB). Its currently 2.6.1+ and no need for compiling. Is also production ready - albeit with the limitations MongoDB 32bit has.

Comment: The package seems to have vanished. Do you still have the binary and the necessary code changes around? If so, could you please create a GitHub project for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [mongodb-linux-armv7l-2.4.1.tgz](https://github.com/carlipa/public/blob/master/files) that I've uploaded, taken from a JIRA comment. An experimental but working build. Not production ready.

Comment: I am getting this error; `./mongod: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./mongod)` when trying to start `mongod`, have no idea what it is about. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @Olivier any update on your arm version of mongodb? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22404/official-mongodb-repo-for-arm-processor

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.4 MongoDb officially supports ARM 64.
One thing to note though: Currently (v3.4.0) Only the Wired Tiger storage engine is currently supported.

The current version can be downloaded here: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.4.0.tgz

Answer (score 0):

You may watch [this](https://github.com/Fourdee/DietPi/issues/889#issuecomment-381025049) thread on Github of DietPi for update.

For now I have tested prebuild [MongoDB 3.0.14 Binaries](https://andyfelong.com/2017/03/mongodb-3-0-14-binaries-for-raspberry-pi-3/) for Odroid XU4 Running [DietPi_OdroidXU4-ARMv7-Jessie](https://dietpi.com/downloads/images/DietPi_OdroidXU4-ARMv7-Jessie.7z) and it is working fine. Pl check bellow screenshot.

MongoDB 3.0.14 Running on Odroid XU4 on DietPi V6.10 (Debian Jessie): 
[image]